# Put age restriction of 18 years - Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using Bootstrap Datepicker.

I want to put an Age Restriction of 18 Years.

Dates less than Age 18 Years from current date should be disabled.

**Here is my Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/kGGCZ/17/

JS:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#datepicker').datepicker(
    {
        viewMode: "years",
        defaultDate: '-2yr', 
    }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply put endDate: '-18y' if you only want to allow user whose age is 18 years and above.

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">

<script>
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  endDate: '-18y'
});
</script>
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/sparshturkane/w46euf5q/1/

Please refer [Bootstrap Date picker docs](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for more options and instructions

Answer (score 1):

This is the JavaScript you are after:

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear()-18);

$('#datepicker').datepicker(
    {
        viewMode: "years",
        endDate : dt
    }
);
```

But your fiddle is using coffeescript so here is the same in coffee:

```
dt = new Date()
dt.setFullYear new Date().getFullYear() - 18
$("#datepicker").datepicker
  viewMode: "years"
  endDate: dt
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln5x6/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use yearRange, to let users choose only years which comes under 18+ from current year. Like,

```
jQuery('#dateob').datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
yearRange: '-110:-18',
showButtonPanel: true
});
```