# How to get year in datetimepicker for validation 18

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to validate that a person is above the age of 18 before they can access the site. I am using datetimepicker in bootstrap.

My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtDOB').datetimepicker({
        maxDate: new Date,
        minDate: new Date(1950, 6, 12),
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var month = dateText.getUTCMonth();
            var day = dateText.getUTCDate();
            var year = dateText.getUTCFullYear();
            alert(day + month + year);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880917/put-age-restriction-of-18-years-bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: it datepicker. i am using bootstrap  date time picker. code is not working

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/B4BzK/291/ ?

Comment: failed to load resource $(document).ready(function () { in this line i am getting error

Comment: and getting error in  var dt = new Date(); this too

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DOB, new { id = "txtDOB", Class = "form-control datepicker minimumSize", @readonly = "@readonly" }) my MVC View textbox control

Comment: its working but i am able to select the current year too. in JSfiddle it showing old year i am able to clicking current year