# Age restriction code on date field

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

There are new laws coming in for ecigarettes and I have to check whether customers are 18. I have added a date field select box to my checkout that they have to fill in their date of birth.

I was wondering if you could use javascript to take the current date take off 18 years and set it so that you can't pick it if you're below that age.

I've been looking around and all of the age restriction addons for big commerce are paid, can anyone offer a solution?

```html
<input type="hidden" class="FormFieldId" value="25"><input type="hidden" class="FormFieldFormId" value="2"><input type="hidden" class="FormFieldType" value="datechooser"><input type="hidden" class="FormFieldPrivateId" value="">
<div id="FormField_25" class="FormField">
  <select name="FormFieldMonth[2][25]" class="formFieldDate field-xsmall Age-reg FormFieldMonth">
  <option value="" selected="">---</option><option value="1">Jan</option><option value="2">Feb</option><option value="3">Mar</option><option value="4">Apr</option><option value="5">May</option><option value="6">Jun</option><option value="7">Jul</option><option value="8">Aug</option><option value="9">Sep</option><option value="10">Oct</option><option value="11">Nov</option><option value="12">Dec</option>
 </select>
  <select name="FormFieldDay[2][25]" class="formFieldDate field-xsmall Age-reg FormFieldDay">
  <option value="" selected="">--</option><option value="1">1st</option><option value="2">2nd</option><option value="3">3rd</option><option value="4">4th</option><option value="5">5th</option><option value="6">6th</option><option value="7">7th</option><option value="8">8th</option><option value="9">9th</option><option value="10">10th</option><option value="11">11th</option><option value="12">12th</option><option value="13">13th</option><option value="14">14th</option><option value="15">15th</option><option value="16">16th</option><option value="17">17th</option><option value="18">18th</option><option value="19">19th</option><option value="20">20th</option><option value="21">21st</option><option value="22">22nd</option><option value="23">23rd</option><option value="24">24th</option><option value="25">25th</option><option value="26">26th</option><option value="27">27th</option><option value="28">28th</option><option value="29">29th</option><option value="30">30th</option><option value="31">31st</option>
 </select>
  <select name="FormFieldYear[2][25]" class="formFieldDate field-xsmall Age-reg FormFieldYear">
  <option value="" selected="">----</option><option value="1917">1917</option><option value="1918">1918</option><option value="1919">1919</option><option value="1920">1920</option><option value="1921">1921</option><option value="1922">1922</option><option value="1923">1923</option><option value="1924">1924</option><option value="1925">1925</option><option value="1926">1926</option><option value="1927">1927</option><option value="1928">1928</option><option value="1929">1929</option><option value="1930">1930</option><option value="1931">1931</option><option value="1932">1932</option><option value="1933">1933</option><option value="1934">1934</option><option value="1935">1935</option><option value="1936">1936</option><option value="1937">1937</option><option value="1938">1938</option><option value="1939">1939</option><option value="1940">1940</option><option value="1941">1941</option><option value="1942">1942</option><option value="1943">1943</option><option value="1944">1944</option><option value="1945">1945</option><option value="1946">1946</option><option value="1947">1947</option><option value="1948">1948</option><option value="1949">1949</option><option value="1950">1950</option><option value="1951">1951</option><option value="1952">1952</option><option value="1953">1953</option><option value="1954">1954</option><option value="1955">1955</option><option value="1956">1956</option><option value="1957">1957</option><option value="1958">1958</option><option value="1959">1959</option><option value="1960">1960</option><option value="1961">1961</option><option value="1962">1962</option><option value="1963">1963</option><option value="1964">1964</option><option value="1965">1965</option><option value="1966">1966</option><option value="1967">1967</option><option value="1968">1968</option><option value="1969">1969</option><option value="1970">1970</option><option value="1971">1971</option><option value="1972">1972</option><option value="1973">1973</option><option value="1974">1974</option><option value="1975">1975</option><option value="1976">1976</option><option value="1977">1977</option><option value="1978">1978</option><option value="1979">1979</option><option value="1980">1980</option><option value="1981">1981</option><option value="1982">1982</option><option value="1983">1983</option><option value="1984">1984</option><option value="1985">1985</option><option value="1986">1986</option><option value="1987">1987</option><option value="1988">1988</option><option value="1989">1989</option><option value="1990">1990</option><option value="1991">1991</option><option value="1992">1992</option><option value="1993">1993</option><option value="1994">1994</option><option value="1995">1995</option><option value="1996">1996</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2014">2014</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2018">2018</option><option value="2019">2019</option><option value="2020">2020</option><option value="2021">2021</option><option value="2022">2022</option><option value="2023">2023</option><option value="2024">2024</option><option value="2025">2025</option><option value="2026">2026</option><option value="2027">2027</option><option value="2028">2028</option><option value="2029">2029</option><option value="2030">2030</option><option value="2031">2031</option><option value="2032">2032</option><option value="2033">2033</option><option value="2034">2034</option><option value="2035">2035</option><option value="2036">2036</option><option value="2037">2037</option><option value="2038">2038</option><option value="2039">2039</option><option value="2040">2040</option><option value="2041">2041</option><option value="2042">2042</option><option value="2043">2043</option><option value="2044">2044</option><option value="2045">2045</option><option value="2046">2046</option><option value="2047">2047</option><option value="2048">2048</option><option value="2049">2049</option><option value="2050">2050</option><option value="2051">2051</option><option value="2052">2052</option><option value="2053">2053</option><option value="2054">2054</option><option value="2055">2055</option><option value="2056">2056</option><option value="2057">2057</option><option value="2058">2058</option><option value="2059">2059</option><option value="2060">2060</option><option value="2061">2061</option><option value="2062">2062</option><option value="2063">2063</option><option value="2064">2064</option><option value="2065">2065</option><option value="2066">2066</option><option value="2067">2067</option><option value="2068">2068</option><option value="2069">2069</option><option value="2070">2070</option><option value="2071">2071</option><option value="2072">2072</option><option value="2073">2073</option><option value="2074">2074</option><option value="2075">2075</option><option value="2076">2076</option><option value="2077">2077</option><option value="2078">2078</option><option value="2079">2079</option><option value="2080">2080</option><option value="2081">2081</option><option value="2082">2082</option><option value="2083">2083</option><option value="2084">2084</option><option value="2085">2085</option><option value="2086">2086</option><option value="2087">2087</option><option value="2088">2088</option><option value="2089">2089</option><option value="2090">2090</option><option value="2091">2091</option><option value="2092">2092</option><option value="2093">2093</option><option value="2094">2094</option><option value="2095">2095</option><option value="2096">2096</option><option value="2097">2097</option><option value="2098">2098</option><option value="2099">2099</option><option value="2100">2100</option><option value="2101">2101</option><option value="2102">2102</option><option value="2103">2103</option><option value="2104">2104</option><option value="2105">2105</option><option value="2106">2106</option><option value="2107">2107</option><option value="2108">2108</option><option value="2109">2109</option><option value="2110">2110</option><option value="2111">2111</option><option value="2112">2112</option><option value="2113">2113</option><option value="2114">2114</option><option value="2115">2115</option><option value="2116">2116</option><option value="2117">2117</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It's the default one from Big Commerce, I've added the code above.

Comment: You can try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880917/put-age-restriction-of-18-years-bootstrap-datepicker, the example there is quite useful.

Comment: He is not using a normal date picker. I see dropdowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete example based on your pasted code. It is handling leap years and all

```js
var months = ["","Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
  nth = function(d) {
    if (d > 3 && d < 21) return 'th'; 
    switch (d % 10) {
      case 1:return "st";
      case 2:return "nd";
      case 3:return "rd";
     default:return "th";
    }
  }

window.onload = function() {
  var date = new Date(),
    yyyy = date.getFullYear(),
    maxDate = new Date(yyyy - 18, date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0),
    maxYear = maxDate.getFullYear(),
    maxMonth = maxDate.getMonth() + 1,
    maxDay = maxDate.getDate(),
    dY = document.querySelector(".FormFieldYear"),
    dM = document.querySelector(".FormFieldMonth"),
    dD = document.querySelector(".FormFieldDay");

  for (var i = yyyy - 100, max = maxYear; i <= max; i++) {
    dY.options[dY.options.length] = new Option(i, i);
  }
  dY.onchange = function() {
    dM.options.length = 1;
    var year = this.value;
    if (this.value == "") return;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
      if (year == maxYear && i > maxMonth) break;
      dM[dM.options.length] = new Option(months[i], i);
    }
  }
  dM.onchange = function() {
    dD.options.length = 1;
    var year = dY.options[dY.selectedIndex].value,
      month = this.value,
      lastDay = new Date(year,month,0).getDate();
    if (this.value == "") return;
    
    for (var i = 1; i <= lastDay; i++) {
      if (year == maxYear && i > maxMonth) break;
      dD[dD.options.length] = new Option(i+nth(i), i);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="FormField_25" class="FormField">
  <select name="FormFieldMonth[2][25]" class="formFieldDate field-xsmall Age-reg FormFieldMonth">
    <option value="">--</option>
  </select>
  <select name="FormFieldDay[2][25]" class="formFieldDate field-xsmall Age-reg FormFieldDay">
    <option value="">--</option>
  </select>
  <select name="FormFieldYear[2][25]" class="formFieldDate field-xsmall Age-reg FormFieldYear">
    <option value="">----</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't yet comment, I just wanted to quickly chime in regarding the legal requirements on selling eCigarretes and eLiquid online in the USA.

According to the FDA law passed in August of 2016, you are required to check the photo ID of any customers under the age of 27 who are making an online purchase.

### FDA Law Snippet (ScreenShot):

[image]

### FDA Law Snippet (Text):

> "...Therefore, the final rule states that retailers of the newly deemed covered tobacco products may not sell them to individuals under 18 years of age and requires retailers of covered tobacco products to verify the purchaser's birth date by reviewing the individual's photographic identification...."
>
> "...a retailer is not required to verify the age of any person who is more than 26 years of age...."
>
> "...Therefore, any sale of covered tobacco products over the Internet must comply with the minimum age and identification requirements in this rule."

---

#### How do you know if someone is under or over 27?

The law is grey here, but in order to ensure maximum compliance, your best bet is to simply **request photo identification of ALL customers on your site**.

My recommended *manual* flow for this is that you place all successfully placed orders on hold, and request that customers send in photo ID via email, after the point of sale. For customers with whom you already have their photo IDs on file, you can safely fulfill their orders.

### How do you know if a photo ID is legitimate?

You can request 3 photos be taken and sent in:

```
 1. The front of the photo ID. 
 2. The back of the photo ID. 
 3. A picture of the customer holding the ID near his/her face.
```

There are then databases you can access (although it requires that your business be vetted and approved) from where you can access the customer's personal information to confirm and his/her identity (customer's address, age, etc) by crosschecking the information and DOB on the photo ID against the results returned from the identity database service.

Although this answer isn't related to your JavaScript question, I hope publishing this information will be useful to some.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and probably not the best solution is to use HTML input date type and some javascript code. Please note that the code below won't work on firefox and IE version 11 or below.

Below is a working code:

```js
function getMaxDate() {
    var millisecondsIn18years = 568080000000;
    var ceil = new Date(Date.now() - millisecondsIn18years);
    var date = ceil.getDate();
    var month = String(ceil.getMonth() + 1);
    month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
    var year = ceil.getFullYear();
    return year + '-' + month + '-'  + date;
}
document.getElementById('dob').max = getMaxDate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
  Birthday:
  <input type="date" name="bday" id="dob">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not a completely working solution. I can select 18th of April 1999 today the 13th of April 2017

Comment: If you are born on 18th of April 1999, does that not make you 18 years old today?

Comment: Not if your 18th is in 5 days

Comment: Oh wait, i thought today is 18th. My bad.

Comment: You are missing leap days